# Semantically correct HTML 5 layout?

Tags: html, semantics

I am in the process of re-designing my portfolio, and I want to test out a design I have put together, I have been reading resources such as HTML 5 doctor and Smashing Books (Redesign the web #3) to try and understand the correct useage of certain HTML 5 tags.

Can any one provide any feedback on whether or not these tags are used correctly in my annotated screenshot?

The GREEN boxes are all `<article>` tags as I can see no other html 5 tag that would suit the purpose of them. The percentage circles are statistics and the bottom at the links in my footer, could I change these to A tags instead?

[image: Annotated layout]

Thanks for any help given, sorry if this question is a little vague.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry if my answer is a little vague, but I don't see any problems with how you used html 5 tag in your annotated screenshot.

Comment: Would you use article tags for the footer or a tags, can I ask?

Comment: Personally, I wouldn't. I usally use article on elements with more content, like a blog entry or stuff like that. I always ask myself would that be relevant enough to be read out of the context? If yes, I use an article. If no, I use a div. But I don't think the way you use it represent a mistake either.

Comment: Thanks Simon, that makes a lot of sense. Thanks for your time - Jon